# Authorize for roles with Individual Authentication in a Blazor project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created my new Blazor project that consists of the server, client and shared projects. I decided to use the **Individual Authentication**. In the server project, I created a simple `SeedRolesAsync` that creates the roles in the database at the start

```
public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                                        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync("SuperAdmin");
    await roleManager.CreateAsync("Basic");
    // ...
}
```

On the client side, the application can recognize if a user is authenticated. In the *Program.cs* I added

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

The `[Authorize]` attribute is working but not for specific roles. For example, I define in a page

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin, Admin")]
```

no one user can have access to that page at all. Same if I use

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="SuperAdmin">
    <Authorizing>
        Authorizing...
    </Authorizing>
    <NotAuthorized>
        You are not an superadmin.
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        You are a superadmin
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

[image]

As you can see, in the `Authorize` attribute I use the same role name as in the database.

### Claims

On the client project, I print the claims and see the user has all the roles I expected. If I check if the user has a role that is present in the claim `role`, the return of `IsInRole` is `false`.

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<h1>ClaimsPrincipal Data</h1>

<button @onclick="GetClaimsPrincipalData">Get ClaimsPrincipal Data</button>

<p>@authMessage</p>

@if (claims.Count() > 0)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            <li>@claim.Type: @claim.Value</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

<p>@surname</p>

<p>Is Admin? @isAdmin</p>

@code {
    private string? authMessage;
    private string? surname;
    private bool isAdmin;

    private IEnumerable<Claim> claims = Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

    private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider
            .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            claims = user.Claims;

            isAdmin = user.IsInRole("SuperAdmin");
            surname = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You will note that your "Role" claim is actually an array of strings. This is the problem. You have to add middleware to transform this claim into multiple role claims one for each role.

https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth/blob/master/RoleBaseAuth/Client/RolesAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs

Comment: Thank you so much @BrianParker your code is working beautifully!